# How to build JSP that allows commenting on every post automatically?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

Actually I want to build a JSP that shows the posts from database and automatically give a place to write text on each post and when user enters the text in comment box that should save in database and immediately text appears and again new text place(comment box) should appear for entering text. Just like Facebook, I search allot from internet but not found any solution any body can help me in that case will be appreciated.

Comment: Try out looking for some jQuery plugin or probably to achieve the functionality

Comment: How to do that, if I knew why I have to ask ?? I am asking about the method .

Comment: Rather than the method,try focusing on which tech/framework which should be suitable for the application you are using.Please add in further details about the techstack of your application and compatibility with the given frameworks!

Comment: actually its final year project and I am building in Java web.
Using MVC framwork.
Front end JSP (using bootstrap instead of simply Html document) and for server side I am using Servlets and for back end I am using a database  for storing purposes. @shivam Aggarwal

Comment: basically its crud app , to store images, articles, embed videos or view posts etc..

Comment: It's your final year project, put more effort in developping it. There are tons of CRUD examples in JSF or JSP, ajax or not. Your question is too broad for answering, you are searching for tutorials, not specific answers.

Comment: You want to use Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Going for a implemenation from scratch would be like re inventing wheel.Your best bet is to use a jQuery library such as [jQuery comments dcoumentation](http://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/)  which will provide you with the whole structure.You need to provide implementation for ajax call to servlet to fetch and post comments.The templates will be in there,only thing is you need to provide implementation for the functions.Let me know for any inputs needed or challenges in using it.

From the given library documentation:

1) Add the following to your HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-comments.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-comments.js"></script>
```

2) Initialize the library

```
$('#comments-container').comments({
    profilePictureURL: 'https://app.viima.com/static/media/user_profiles/user-icon.png',
    getComments: function(success, error) {
        var commentsArray = [{
            id: 1,
            created: '2015-10-01',
            content: 'Lorem ipsum dolort sit amet',
            fullname: 'Simon Powell',
            upvote_count: 2,
            user_has_upvoted: false
        }];
        success(commentsArray);
    }
});
```

The `getComments` and `postComments` need to be customized.
So,for posting comments,below function needs to be used,mapped to your servlet mapping,for posting comments,making an ajax call:

```
$('#comments-container').comments({
    postComment: function(commentJSON, success, error) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/api/comments/',
            data: commentJSON,
            success: function(comment) {
                success(comment)
            },
            error: error
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: But he's asking for a jsp solution.

Comment: But then this will be part of the Jsp only and subsequently,the comment interactions need to be handled at the servlet level only.This needs to be part of the front end layer only.

Comment: Sure, I think this is probably a nicer (more modern) solution then through pure JSP, mostly because you won't need page refreshes. But it might be out of the scope for his assignment. I do agree with the voters that his question is too broad to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.includehelp.com/java/comment-box-design-in-bootstrap-using-ajax-mysql-and-jsp.aspx

follow this, you can implement the same